# Can't uploading base 64 to imgur

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, base64, sails.js

```
    up: function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.param('image'));
    imgurwrap.setClientID('myImgurClientID')
    imgurwrap.uploadImageBase64({
        image: req.param('image'),
        title: 'sfdsf',
        description: 'sfsdf'
    }, function(err, res) {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(err);
    });
},
```

This code returns me an url with an empty image like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3t2JV.png . However if I declare a variable and put my encoded base64 string in it, it works.
So I thought some data was appened in the request but a diff showed no difference. I've tried others npm imgur modules and it's always the same behavior so something must be wront on my side but I can't figure it out..

Comment: Try posting question on to here. They might have some answers. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails